# Htaccess code in if else

Tags: .htaccess

How to write .htaccess file like that given below code. I have tried this code in my local system. My development site uses PHP, with Apache server using LAMP. I got an internal server error.

Code for htaccess file:

Hi my appache server version : 2.2.22

`<if "%{REQUEST_URI}!='/admin/home.php'">
    # do something
    </if>`

Its not worked ? help us ASAP thanks,

Hi justin,

Example: I have to set some restriction for admin page access only 
( www.domain.com/admin/home.php)  I want to restrict admin access only ?

Comment: Is this the content of your `.htaccess` file, or a PHP file?

Comment: it is .htaccess file thanks

Comment: What is your `do something` ?

Comment: What version of Apache do you have? If statements are only available in 2.4+

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do in `# do something`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Apache version 2.4+ you could solve your problem by

- Creating a .htaccess file in your website root using `RewriteEngine`, which redirects everyone whose IP address **isn't** 0.0.0.0 to /index.php

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^0\.0\.0\.0
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/home.php
  RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
  ```
- Creating a .htaccess file in the /admin subfolder, showing "Error 403: Permission denied" to everyone whose IP address **isn't** 0.0.0.0:

  ```
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from 0.0.0.0
  ```

Comment: I have checked the with case it s not worked got internal server error thanks,

Comment: After searching for a while I think the most probable cause is, as ChrisW points out above, that your Apache version does not support if statements.